# SwiftyJSON string-value empty

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have a problem with parsing JSON in Swift. I use the SwiftyJSON-framework.

My data comes from the network:

```
let dataString : NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
```

printing this:

```
println("Received data: \(dataString)")
```

gives my JSON:

```
Received data: {"result":"success"}
```

But when I try to read the result-value:

```
let json = JSON(dataString);
println(json["result"].stringValue); //<-- empty string
```

then the output is empty. I've tried different approaches, like:

```
println(json[1]["result"].stringValue); //<-- empty string
println(json["result"]); //<-- prints "null"
```

but nothing worked so far. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
This is server side (Java):

```
    String response = client.isAuthenticated() ? "success" : "fail";
    client.send(new JSONObject().put("result", response).toString());
```

To read the data I use CocoaAsyncSocket:

```
func socket(sock: GCDAsyncSocket!, didReadData data: NSData!, withTag tag: Int)
```

The error I get is:

> Dictionary["result"] failure, It is not an dictionary

**Edit2:**
I found out that the problem is in the data:

```
let dataFromString = dataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)?
```

has a length of 22 bytes. If I set

```
dataString : NSString = "{\"result\":\"success\"}"
```

and do the same again, its length is 20 bytes. My data has two bytes 0x0014 at beginning:

```
<7b227265 73756c74 223a2273 75636365 7373227d>  //<-- correct
<00147b22 72657375 6c74223a 22737563 63657373 227d> // <-- mine
```

If I remove the two byes with

```
dataFromString!.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(2, 20))
```

the JSON can be parsed correctly.

**Edit3 (my Solution):**

The problem was the DataOutputStream I used in the Java-Service. It added two bytes to my JSON. I replaced it with BufferedOutputStream and now it works as expected.

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#initialization: JSON() expects an JSON object, not a string. Use JSON(data:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the `NSData` from the String, and initialize the JSON object with it, here's an example:

```
let dataString : NSString = "{\"result\":\"success\"}"

if let dataFromString = dataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
   let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
    print(json["result"])
}
```

Read More: [SwiftyJSON - initialization](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#initialization)

Comment: Okay I found out that the problem is in the data. Your dataString contains 20 bytes (as expected) whereas mine contains 22 bytes. I don't know where those extra 2 bytes come from..

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I guess 2 bytes won't have that impact, the service might have returned with extra spaces or something, anyhow have you tested my data for example ?

Comment: Yes, your example works. I tried to remove the first two bytes from my data and then my code works too. The bytes are 0x0014. I'll edit my question to address this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should construct `JSON` with `init(data:)` constructor with `NSData`.

Try:

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
```